# How can I set JSON into a variable from a local url

Tags: javascript, json

Evidently jQuery has made me dumb.

I've got a local url that serves up raw JSON, and I can't figure out how to consume that json from within my method without using jQuery.

Here's how I know to do it WITH jQuery

```
var myJson;
$.getJSON('/local/path/to/json', function (data) { 
    myJson = data; 
});

// Now I can use myJson in a method.
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to use JS to get the contents of that file? Or, once you have the contents, how to turn it into a JS object?

Comment: Yes, I need to get the contents of the file using JavaScript.

Comment: your question is still vague.  _Parsing_ JSON is trivial, but you appear to be asking how to _obtain_ the file without using jQuery (using `XMLHttpRequest`) ?

Comment: and please define "local".  Do you mean `file:///`, or `http://localhost/`, or something else?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell [You'll need to use AJAX.](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ajax+tutorial)

Comment: @Alnitak, local url `http://localhost/local/path/to/json`

Comment: @ChaseFlorell right, so you still need to use AJAX.  And if you still have jQuery in the project you might as well use it.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell p.s. your sample code above won't work correctly unless you make a **synchronous** AJAX call.  As written `myJSON` will be undefined when the `$.getJSON` method returns.

Comment: @Alnitak, this was my original working code `var filterPrases = ''; $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ProfanityFilter","Generic")', function (data) { filterPrases = data; });` --- note: it's using Razor.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell @pradeek gave a longer explanation in an answer - you shouldn't use your `filterPhrases` variable until you know that the asynchronous `success` function has been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve the JSON string from a server use `XMLHttpRequest` object as described in this reference:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

You'll find that it's quite involved with all the unseen things you need to account and check for. Thus libraries like jQuery.

To convert the JSON string to a javascript object, use `JSON.parse()`. Here's the reference:

http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON

Here's an example:

```
function readJSON(file) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.send(null);
    if (request.status == 200)
        return request.responseText;
};

var myObject = JSON.parse(readJSON('/local/path/to/json'));
```

EDIT #2: Thanks for editing in this example, Chase. A word of warning. It is not a good idea to make the `open()` method a synchronous call by using `false` in the 3rd parm. AJAX is intentionally designed for asynchronous use, and to make a synchronous call invites lock ups. As one who used to think there was a place for synchronous calls, I now find there's always a better way to get it done asynchronously. Word to the wise.

Comment: yes, I get that, but how to I get `myJSONString` from `http://example.com/local/path/to/json`?

Comment: I edited. It's quite an involved process that involves writing several functions yourself for handling all the ins and outs. Is there a reason you don't want to do this in jQuery? If it's just for learning, that's an excellent reason to roll your own.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Example:_Asynchronous_request or https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Example:.C2.A0Synchronous_request apparently sync has event/memory leaks according to that page so they recommend async (the first link)

Comment: Thanks, @acidzombie24. Chase, that example will get you started, but there's much more to it if you're going to be doing much serious work with it. Take a good hard look at the reference, do lots experimenting. It's very educational rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

I you're familiar with jQuery, this is a drop-in replacement for `$.ajax`:

Script:

```
function ajax( uri, settings ) {
    var ajax = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),
        data = settings.type == 'GET' ? '' : settings.data,
        async = settings.async ? settings.async : false;
        uri = settings.type == 'GET' ? uri + ( settings.data ? '?' + settings.data : '' ) : uri;

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) { //response ready
            if ( ajax.status == 200 ) { //success
                if ( settings.success ) settings.success( ajax.responseText, ajax.statusText );
                if ( settings.complete ) settings.complete( ajax, ajax.statusText );
            } else {
                if ( settings.error ) settings.error( ajax, ajax.status, ajax.statusText );
            };
        };
    };

    ajax.open( settings.type, uri, async );

    if ( settings.headers ) {
        for ( var header in settings.headers ) {
            ajax.setRequestHeader( header, settings.headers[header] );
        };
    };

    ajax.send( data );
};
```

Call it just like jQuery:

```
ajax( '/local/path/to/json', {
    "type": "GET", //or "POST"
    //"data": "<query string>", //if POST
    "success": function ( data, status ) {
        var myJson = window.JSON.parse( data );
    },
    "error": function ( response, status, error ) {
        // handle error
    }
} );
```

Comment: This is pretty heavy for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at be below code snap which will on in all browsers, thanks

```
    function getJSONData(jsonurl) {
        var req = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) { }
            }
        }
        req.open('GET', jsonurl, false);
        req.send(null);
        return req.status == 200 ? req.responseText : 'Error occurred';
    }
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(getJSONData('/local/path/to/json'));
    alert(getJSONData('/local/path/to/json'));
```

Hope this will be very helpful, thanks for your time

Comment: blek, `ActiveX`? I don't care to support obsolete browsers, so I think I'll pass.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, still many users in the world are using the earlier versions of various browsers and I've considered to all, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I appreciate the need to support older browsers in specific applications. For my particular needs, I would rather just not deal with the hassle. I won't be any better a person, or generating any additional revenues by doing so. Thank you for your answer, and I'm sure it will be very helpful for others who do need to support said browsers.

Comment: Wow, that is awful. But Microsoft were very late to the party – IE7 and 8 still needs this kind of nastiness to work. Which is why most people just use jQuery or similar libraries to avoid having to write stuff like this :)